# Laravel - Locale session after login

Tags: laravel

I have a application in Laravel. I try to get user language and translate app based on this.

I create a middleware and execute it in all routes (maybe isn't necessary) to translate in this sessions all text.

Middleware groups

```
 protected $middlewareGroups = [
            'web' => [
                \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
                \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
                \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
                // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
                \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
                \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
                \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
                \App\Http\Middleware\ChangeLang::class, //Locale Middleware in all routes, maybe isn´t necessary
            ],
```

Locale

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Auth;

class ChangeLang
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        if (Auth::user()) {
            app()->setLocale(session(Auth::user()->language));
        }

        return $response;

    }
}
```

*Auth::user()->language* returns correct language but something is wrong that doesn't translate anything.

So, anyone knows what´s wrong?

Comment: Why are you wrapping `Auth::user()->language` with `session()`? If you do `dd(session(Auth::user()->language))`, what does that return? Is that valid with `setLocale()` (which expects a language code, like `en`, `fr`, `es`, etc.)? (Sidenote, I didn't downvote; not sure why someone did)

Comment: I tried also app()->setLocale(Auth::user()->language)) and app()->setLocale('es') and doesn´t work. Maybe the error is in other part.

Comment: Hmm ok, so not that. Can you better explain what "doesn't work" means? Show the screen you're looking at, provide your translations, etc etc. At a glance, that code should work to properly set the Locale via Middleware, so if translations are available for `es`, they should be used.

Comment: Is the middleware getting applied? What does `dd(app()->getLocale())` tell you? Also the `$request` variable should give you access to the user without calling `Auth::user()` twice. And as Tim Lewis said, get rid of the call to `session()`, not sure why that would even be in there.

Comment: Where are the translations supposed to be? I have a Resource -> Lang. Inside of this i have es.json and en.json.